# How to add '@testing-library/jest-dom' globally?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I saw in a project using `create-react-app` a file named `setupTest.js` which just imports `@testing-library/jest-dom` and the tests seems to use the extented `expect` version, like `.toBeInTheDocument`.

I added the same file (`setupTest.js`) to my project but seems to be no effect.

In other words, how can I import `@testing-library/jest-dom` globally instead of doing in every `.spec.ts` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `jest.config.js` file and add `setupFilesAfterEnv` property to it and configure it to your `setupTests.js` file address like this:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/app/config/setupTests.js"],
};
```

and then in your `setupTests.js` add this code:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

Comment: This works! Out of curiosity... jest.config.js can be a JSON file?

Comment: @Skhaz This link can help you https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration